# Axios doesn't GET data in React render but it does in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm building an e-commerce website and i'm trying to get an image data stored in MongoDB and must be rendered after fetching it with `axios`.
The problem is that the image doesn't render at all, even thought in console i can see the product data alongside with `img` data inside of it :

*Console.dev:* (URL: `http://localhost:3000/product/62cc53596d10ae0a3c0af373`)

```
Object
product:
categories: (2) ['coat', 'women']
color: ['Yellow']
createdAt: "2022-07-11T16:44:09.859Z"
desc: "COTTON MINI RIPSTOP/ELASTHANE"
img: "https://www.pngarts.com/files/3/Women-Jacket-PNG-High-Quality-Image.png"
inStock: true
price: 70
size: (2) ['XL', 'M']
title: "Women Jacket"
updatedAt: "2022-07-11T16:44:09.859Z"
__v: 0
_id: "62cc53596d10ae0a3c0af373"
```

Network's tab shows no errors, and test with postman successfully gets all product's id data. Am i missing something which cause image doesn't render?

*JSX code:*

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { publicRequest } from "../requestMethods";

//...
const Image = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  ${mobile({ height: "40vh" })};
`;
//...

const Product = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/" + id);
        setProduct(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    getProduct();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Navbar />
        <Annoncement />
        <Wrapper>
          <ImgContainer>
            <Image src={product.img} />
          </ImgContainer>
          //...
```

RequestMethodes.js code:

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';
const TOKEN = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyYzZmYWM2NWE0MzA2YWM4OGFljIzZCIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTY1NzczOTA5NCwiZXwIjoxNjY1NTE1MDk0fQ.DtQVQXrEeUMPFa6xvZQuHwh1FpOCbtYI_UEQTwhtRc";

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    header: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` }
});
```

**Edit:**
`console.log(product.img)` after `return` print `undefined`.

Comment: Can you post the code of the Image component

Comment: Look in the network tab see if request fires for the image+make sure the img url goes to the img html tag

Comment: @MridulGupta question updated

Comment: @gaditzkhori `make sure the img url goes to the img html tag` how to make sure of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem by changing `<Image src={product.img} />` to `<Image src={product?.product?.img} />`

Check this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for more information about **Optional chaining**.